# How to set the value of GhostDown Markdown editor

Tags: javascript, markdown

I'm working on a simple note taking application and using GhostDown Markdown editor. It's pretty nice, I like it, but I am stuck trying to set it's value programatically.

I can get values out pretty easily. $('.entry-markdown-content textarea').val()

Setting it however is another story... :(

Prototype of what I'm working on can be seen at http://potusnotes.com

Comment: you are on this [Ghost-Markdown-Editor](https://github.com/timsayshey/Ghost-Markdown-Editor) version ?

Comment: @Blag not sure, but if you provide the answer for the latest version, I will be sure to update if necessary

Comment: it was more about the fork than the version (As I don't find an official site for GhostDown Markdown editor ); I've take a look on the source code, but it's a bit messy <_> ; it seem to have `getMarkdown` and `getHtml`, but no setter... ; and as they use an overlay, if you don't find the right method, it's pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *editor* part, Ghost-Markdown-Editor uses [CodeMirror editor](http://codemirror.net/2/doc/manual.html).
So, to set value programmatically, we would call CodeMirror's instance and do

```
editor.setValue(txt);
```

But how to get that CM instance? It was created by the widget with which Ghost-Markdown-Editor was created. See *jquery.ghostdown.js* file:

```
$.widget( "b4m.ghostDown", {
    editor: null,
    // ...
    _create: function() {
        // ...
        this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.element.find('textarea')[0], {
            mode: 'markdown',
            tabMode: 'indent',
            lineWrapping: true
        });
    }

}
```

As the widget was made with jQuery Widget factory, a widget instance is kept [inside .data("plugin-name")](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/#instance-invocation) element of the object it was used on.

Thus we can access widget instance and set editor value like this:

```
var ghostdown = $(".editor").data("b4m-ghostDown");
ghostdown.editor.setValue("# Hello, SO");
```

Or simply

```
$(".editor").data("b4m-ghostDown").editor.setValue("# Hello, SO");
```

Comment: Great, thank you much, this exactly what I was looking for. I thought it would be something like that but had trouble figuring it out myself.

Comment: Glad I could help! Luckily it was CodeMirror under the hood.